# Finding where a process was run from

Tags: c++, process

So i have an issue that i have an application that gets started. Then through a test i need to turn it off and start it again. But it needs t obe done without hard coding.

So is there a way of finding where a process was run from? I can find a list of all processes running but dont know if this is even possible.

EDIT: Its on a windows 7 OS.

Comment: As it this would need to be OS specific, you should mention what OS API you want to use.

Comment: Assuming we're talking about Windows, it'd definitely make Windows nervous to let your program get such information, but possible yes.  I'm not convinced if it's the right thing to do though in your situation.  Programs don't manage their own processes normally.  That's left to be done by the one who launched it, but I assume then that you don't have access to modify the launcher?

Comment: Do you mean the path of the process executable or the original current directory of a process?

Answer (score 1):

[QueryFullProcessImageName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will provide the path to the executable image for a process:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char exe_path[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD exe_path_size = MAX_PATH;
    if (QueryFullProcessImageName(GetCurrentProcess(),
                                  0,
                                  exe_path,
                                  &exe_path_size))
    {
        std::cout << exe_path << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy and portable way would be using argv[0].
It returns the full .exe file path which is all you need

Answer (score 0):

First, what do you mean by "find where the process is run from"? I'm assuming you mean the parent's process id, but it could mean current working directory, ip of remote call, etc...

To find the parent's process id, look into [getppid()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getppid.html).

Edit: this assumes that you (like any sane programmer) are using a unix-like machine.

Edit #2: You're on Windows, so I have no idea.

Edit #3: Since you're looking for the path to the program you are executing, use argv[0]. The first command line arg to int main(int argc, char* argv[]) is always the path to the binary.

Comment: I mean the location of the exe. And no, we dont get Unix machines